# What does `cond` in `if (!cond(it.next()))` stand for?

Tags: java, iterator, conditional-statements

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn the concept of iterator. I have encountered this code at Java Tutorial Oracle. My question is, what does `cond` in `if (!cond(it.next()))` stands for. the documentation did not specify what `cond()` represents.

```
static void filter(Collection<?> c) {
    for (Iterator<?> it = c.iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
        if (!cond(it.next()))
            it.remove();
}
```

Comment: it stands for "condition"

Comment: so what does it do in this context? sorry if my question sounds silly, only only two months into learning java

Comment: It's actually a method. Check if there's a method named `cond` in your code. It will call that method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cond` stands for "condition". Put that in your context:

```
if (!cond(it.next()))
```

It means that,

> "if your next item in an iteration/collection doesn't match certain condition"

then removes it:

```
if (!cond(it.next()))
    it.remove();
```

Thus you get the name "filter"

```
static void filter(Collection<?> c)
```

The `cond` is a method that checks the validity of your passed argument. It is up to you to define the method for `cond` according to what fits to the situation. I guess the tutorial simply writes as `cond` to suggest that the method should be a checking "condition" and it *is* a method.

As for the checking condition alone, yt is *not* necessarily a method though, for you might have a checking condition like this:

```
if (it.next() != something)
```

Answer (score 1):

The cond may represent any method which you could use to define a criteria to be used for the iterate objects (it.next()) of the Collection in order to be deleted

```
 public boolean cond(Object input)
```